# Honeywell thermostat doesn't seem to be connected to standby generator

Tags: thermostat

Honeywell thermometer doesn't seem to be connected to standby generator. Heater is linked to generator panel, but thermostat loses power with outage. Ideas??Thanks

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your furnace/air-handler and at your thermostat?

Answer (score 2):

There is likely a 24V transformer *somewhere* that connects to both the thermostat and furnace. From what you described, my hunch is that the thermostat is on a separate circuit, not together with the furnace.

It could be a [wall wart like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075PN6NCV) or it could be [a direct wired transformer like this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Honeywell-24-Volt-Transformer-AT72D/202264717), in which case it may be mounted in or on the furnace (though then it would *normally* pull power from the same circuit), or it could be mounted to a junction box nearby.

Once you find it, you need to either move the circuit to the generator panel, or move the transformer to a different circuit that is already on the generator panel.